# Configure sp_add_schedule to run on the first day of every X months/weeks

Tags: sql-server, jobs

I need to configure my jobs scheduling dynamically.

The jobs will always run on the first day of the week once every X weeks. Same for months.

Looking at the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187320.aspx),

I see that for weeks option I would need to use `freq_type=8` (weekly) with `freq_interval=1` (Sunday). But which parameter should be used to mark that the repetition should be once every X weeks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe **@freq_recurrence_factor** is the parameter you are looking for.